# How to save xls{,x} as csv file so that formulas show as text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large spreadsheet in which many of the cells contain formulas.

How can I produce a delimited-text version of this spreadsheet such that all formulas appear as the text of their source code?

For example, for a spreadsheet in which column `A` is

```
14
59
27
```

cell `B1` is set to `=SUM(A:A)`, and all remaining cells are empty, if we did "Save As" CSV, the resulting `*.csv` file would look like this (last two cells of second column are empty):

```
14,100
59,
27,
```

In contrast, what I want would look this:

```
14,=SUM(A:A)
59,
27,
```

In fact, the non-formula values are unimportant (except as placeholders), so the alternative below would be fine too.  Here the only non-empty cells are those corresponding to the formula-containing cells in the original sheet; in this case, the leading '=' can can be omitted from the non-empty cells:

```
,SUM(A:A)
,
,
```

Thanks!

PS. I'm VBA-illiterate, so I'd like to avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just tested it and it's a lot easier than I thought to get output like the 2nd case you specified.

Do the following:

1. Input all your data/formulas
2. Select the `Show Formulas` button (via `Formulas` > `Formula Auditing` in Excel 2007)
3. Save As filetype `CSV(MS-DOS)`
4. Open resultant file in Notepad to verify.

I'll play around with it for a bit more to see if I can get it to pare down the formulas like you mentioned in case 3.

Answer (score 3):

The same applies for LibreOffice Calc (Version: 6.0.6.2):

1. Show formulas (`` Ctrl+` ``),
2. Select "Save as" (`Shift+Ctrl+S`),
3. Select "Text CSV (.csv)" from the list
4. Tick "Save cell formulas instead of calculated values"